# Remove small border when applying overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following page (zoomed in):

[image]

which is the result of having the next html:

```
<div class="background-dark-brown p-2 light-brown">
    <div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">
        <div class="position-absolute overflow-hidden top-0 left-0 w-100 h-100 border-brown background-dark-brown"></div>
        <div class="position-absolute corner top right border-brown background-dark-brown"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the closest I could come up with the shape I want to build which is the "inverted" border radius with border in the perimeter if that makes sense. As you can see the first absolute div is making the actual thin border that appears in the picture even though I did set the overflow hidden and the next element is being rendered after. I have also tried to set z-index +9999 to the second div but it did make no difference. What I noticed was that if I modify the box-sizing it was gone somehow but the whole thing becomes a mess.

My question is whether I can add some sort of CSS to make that line go away.

The extra css I have here (I'm using mostly bootstrap):

```
.corner {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.top { 
    top: -15px;
}

.bottom { 
    bottom: -15px;
}

.left { 
    left: -15px; 
}

.right { 
    right: -15px 
};
```

**UPDATE**

Added Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/carlostorrecillas/q7mrtjpw/2/

As I'm using Angular, I wonder if there could be something strange to do with any of the packages I'm using:

```
"@angular/animations": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.13",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.16",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.8.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.8.0",
    "@nguniversal/common": "7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "7.1.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "luxon": "1.13.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.9.0"
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to reproduce the problem. It seems when the code is inside an absolute element it renders the lines I was mentioning. Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/carlostorrecillas/x9se4bc2/1/

Comment: You could try adding `background:transparent`

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but it might be that your div with classes `position-relative overflow-hidden` has a border. So try  adding a new class with: `border:0;` to that div

Comment: Could you create a fiddle from your existing code? Without having all used CSS rules at hand it's hard to diagnose what causes the thin line.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try to create one. It's definitely the position-absolute div that has the actual border which is making that thin line

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas, are you using any border to class- my-container ? as it looks good in fiddle which you provided

Comment: @NagaSaiA no, I'm just using the CSS I pasted in there. I wonder if that could be related to the version I'm using for bootstrap or something. It's super weird. I have added to the Fiddle my main styles.scss on top of the component scss (I'm using an Angular app) to see if that makes any difference but I could not see any error.

Comment: Looks good to me. What browser are you seeing the lines in?

Comment: Aha! Yeah, it's happening in Chrome but not in FF @RutherfordWonkington

Comment: I'm using Chrome and not seeing the lines.  This may be a wonky rounding error on the part of the browser, I've experienced similar things when trying to position elements flush with others.  Not sure if it will help but I made a version that uses background + padding instead of border, maybe another approach will resolve it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrysw56p/2/)

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington thanks so much! your fiddle wasn't entirely working for me (in my application). I had to remove the padding: 2px from the container and realized that adding: *, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
} in my component fixed it. The reboot.scss was setting the box-sizing to border-box so I'm not sure about this. Anyhow that is now working. Thanks a lot! Edit: hold on...I zommed in and that is still there...one sec

Comment: I have updated my Fiddle because it looks like the problem is coming from the parent div which is set to position absolute with some transforms: https://jsfiddle.net/carlostorrecillas/x9se4bc2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Updating the .my-container to also tuck in it's border solves it for this example.

```
.my-container {
    height: 525px;
    width: 305px;
    background: #dea762;
    padding: 2px;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);

}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: Revised image]

This creates a mask around the offending part. Obviously this only solves it for this example. You may wish to consider a different layout to solve it generically.

The two additional lines are as follows:

```
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
```

This will mask the corner colours.

Comment: I added that to the fiddle I have and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas I had to press "run" again in jsfiddle. The corner disappears for me in Chrome.

Comment: If you zoom in you can see the rounder border even in your screenshot

Comment: One last try @CarlosTorrecillas my eyesight must be failing!!

Comment: Hehe now after you’ve edited the answer it’s not showing up indeed!

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas do the changes work for you though? (as in the translate & mask)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, and I am sure the border will not be visible,  because it is definitly hidden under the child element that render the edges.

Basically im just overlaying the rounded edges over the original border of the `parent`, 
then hiding the overflow in `overflow_hider`

```css
.padder{
 padding: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: brown;
}

.overflow_hider{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.parent{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 5px solid gold;
 background-color: brown;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.edge{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px; 
 background-color: brown;
 border-radius: 50px; 
 border: 5px solid gold;
}

.edge_tl{
 position: absolute;
 top: -35px; /* 50px * 1/2 + 5px because of 5px border of parent + 5px from own boarder  */
 left: -35px; /* 50px * 1/2 + 5px because of 5px border of parent + 5px from own boarder  */

}

/* SAME GOES for the other edges */
.edge_tr{
 position: absolute;
 top: -35px;
 right: -35px;
}

.edge_bl{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -35px;
 left: -35px;
}

.edge_br{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -35px;
 right: -35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padder">
  <div class="overflow_hider">
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="edge edge_tl"></div>
    <div class="edge edge_tr"></div>
    <div class="edge edge_bl"></div>
    <div class="edge edge_br"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```